# Testing tools for REST that support HTTP PATCH?

Tags: testing, rest

I am currently implementing and ROA and need a testing tool to test my RESTful web services.  Currently, we are using SOAP UI to do so.  However, it doesn't appear that SOAP UI supports the HTTP PATCH verb.  Does anyone have any recommendations for a tool that supports HTTP PATH?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, Fiddler supports any arbitrary method.

Answer (score 0):

[Swat](https://github.com/melezhik/swat) is a curl, Perl based DSL for automation testing web, rest services. As swat uses curl to create http requests, PATCH is not a problem, currently swat restricts http verbs to `get, post, put, delete list` list. Please open an [issue](https://github.com/melezhik/swat/issues) on swat github project and I will add PATCH support with minimal efforts.

(*) disclosure - I am the author of swat.